# Inserir Numero Sequencial numa coluna C#

Tags: c#, banco-de-dados, select, inserir

Tenho esta tabela chamada ***ArticleBarCode***:

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

Na coluna ***Code*** preciso de inserir um número sequencial, ou seja, tenho que ler o número máximo que lá está e inserir o próximo que estiver disponível !
Tenho que usar a seguinte linha de código para ver qual é o valor disponível:

```
SELECT ISNULL(MAX(Code), 0) + 1 FROM ArticleBarCode
```

Alguém me sabe ajudar com esta situação ? Obrigado !

Este é o código que eu uso para inserir valores nesta tabela:

```
conn.Open();
comm.CommandText = @"INSERT INTO ArticleBarCode(Code, Code_Article, BarCode, CreatedBy, CreatedOn, ModifiedBy, ModifiedOn, IsDeleted)
                                   VALUES (@code, @codearticle, @barcode, 1, @date, 1, @date, 0)";
comm.Parameters.AddWithValue("@code", next);
comm.Parameters.AddWithValue("@codearticle", code);
comm.Parameters.AddWithValue("@barcode", numbercode);
comm.Parameters.AddWithValue("@date", DateTime.Now);
comm.ExecuteNonQuery();
conn.Close();
```

Aquele ***next*** tem que ser o valor sequencial ! O resto funciona tudo.

Tenho este código que consegue ir buscar o próximo valor disponível e depois tento inserir:

```
 conn.Open();
 SqlCommand cmd5 = new SqlCommand("SELECT ISNULL(MAX(Code), 0) + 1 FROM ArticleBarCode", conn);
 Int32 next = (Int32) cmd5.ExecuteScalar();
 conn.Close();

 conn.Open();
 comm.CommandText = @"INSERT INTO ArticleBarCode(Code, Code_Article, BarCode, CreatedBy, CreatedOn, ModifiedBy, ModifiedOn, IsDeleted)
                    VALUES (@code, @codearticle, @barcode, 1, @date, 1, @date, 0)";
  comm.Parameters.AddWithValue("@code", next);
  comm.Parameters.AddWithValue("@codearticle", code);
  comm.Parameters.AddWithValue("@barcode", numbercode);
  comm.Parameters.AddWithValue("@date", DateTime.Now);
  comm.ExecuteNonQuery();
  conn.Close();
```

Mas quando executo isto, dá-me este erro:

> The INSERT statement conflicted with the FOREIGN KEY constraint
>   "FK_ArticleBarCode_Article". The conflict occurred in database
>   "CardozuGestDB", table "dbo.Article", column 'Code'.

Comment: Já tentou marcar a coluna como identity?

Comment: @Randrade a coluna é identity, ela é a chave primária

Comment: Se a coluna é a identidade da tabela, então qualquer tentativa de atribuir um valor arbitrário a ela resultará em erro. Quem controla o valor que cada registro recebe é o banco ;) Em outras palavras, você não informa o valor que essa coluna terá.

Comment: @Randrade acabei de ver e acho que afinal a coluna nao é identity, fui às propriedades da coluna na base de dados e la à frente de identity diz "false"

Comment: Se não tiver, você pode adicionar. Todavia, você pode alterar a sua tabela, adicionar a `sequence` e você nem precisaria alterar nada em seu código C#

Comment: @Randrade Acontece que não fui eu que criei a base de dados, só posso trabalhar com ela

Comment: @Randrade já consegui ir buscar o próximo valor disponivel mas agora acontece que nao consigo inserir, vou editar a pergunta para voce ver

Comment: Se você tem permissão para editar, você consegue fazer isso. Caso não tenha, complica um pouco mais.

Comment: @Randrade pois, nao tenho essas permissoes

Comment: @Randrade já editei o código para que possa ver o erro que me dá

Comment: @DC a minha impressão é que deu erro de FK porque está faltando na tabela Article o item com o mesmo `Code` que você está tentando inserir na `ArticleBarCode`, já tentou inserir na Article primeiro?

Comment: @FilipeAndradeLopes Foi exatamente isso que corrigi e funcionou ! muito obrigado

Comment: @DC de nada!!! Vota no meu comentário plz...